# Next.js dynamic route template

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I want to create a dynamic route structure for my next.js project, so the main directory would be `countries` and there will be many other countries under that directory.

```
www.mysite.com/countries
www.mysite.com/countries/united-states
www.mysite.com/countries/france
www.mysite.com/countries/united-kingdom
....
```

In my pages folder, I create a folder called `countries` and created a file `[...slug].js`. I have to create a file `index.js` inside the `countries` folder for `www.mysite.com/countries` to be accessible.

The issue is that `index.js` and `[...slug].js` have the same code, and I want to have only 1 file to maintain. How can I configure nextjs to use `[...slug].js` for `www.mysite.com/countries` and any sub pages under it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change `[...slug].js` to `[[...slug]].js` to catch all routes starting with `countries`. It is treated as optional URL parameters in NextJs.
[Official NextJs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) also said that:

> Catch all routes can be made optional by including the parameter in double brackets

Comment: thanks, that did it, I dont know how I missed it